# What should be the definition of DFT in plain English from mathematical point of view?

Tags: fourier-transform

What should be the definition of DFT in plain English from mathematical point of view?

*Signal Processing definition*

DFT is a technique which converts a discrete signal from time domain to frequency domain representation.

.

*Mathematical definition*

???

.

I can think of the following:

*Discrete Fourier Transform is a technique of converting a sequence of N complex numbers into a new sequence of N complex numbers.*

But, its incomplete and not satisfactory.

Comment: I wrote a brief explanation here, although it's not quite in the form of a definition: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/582626/40119

Comment: @littleO, hard to understand. Bookish language.

Answer (score 4):

Not really a definition. DFT is an umbrella concept that to an algebraist looks something like:

A discrete Fourier transform on a finite Abelian group $G$ is the process of representing a function $f:G\to\Bbb{C}$ as a linear combination of the group $\hat{G}$ of characters $\chi:G\to\Bbb{C}$. Because $\hat{\hat{G}}=G$ in a natural way, we always also have an inverse transform.

- Some authors may restrict the scope to cyclic groups $G=\Bbb{Z}_N$, when the characters are of the form $\chi(\overline{n})=e^{2\pi i nk/N}$. Here $k=0,1,\ldots,N-1$ parametrizes the characters, and $\overline{n}\in G$ is an arbitrary element.
- When $G$ is an elementary 2-abelian group, many authors call it a Hadamard transformation instead of a DFT. Or a Walsh-Hadamard transformation.
- Any finite abelian group is a direct product of cyclic groups, and in such cases some authors call the resulting transformation a $k$-dimensional DFT ($k$= the number of component groups). Walsh-Hadamard transform is a special case of this where all the component groups are cyclic of order two.
- It is possible to replace $\Bbb{C}$ with a suitable field $K$ of positive characteristic. To get a nice theory we need $N=|G|\cdot 1_K$ to be invertible in $K$. The resulting DFT is used in many algorithms handling encoding and error correction with cyclic codes.

In all the above cases the DFT/IFT pair works because we have the orthogonality relations (familiar to some of you from representation theory of finite groups):
$$
\sum_{x\in G}\chi(x)=\begin{cases}|G|,&\ \text{if $\chi$ is the trivial character, and}\\0,&\ \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
As well as the dual result
$$
\sum_{\chi\in \hat{G}}\chi(x)=\begin{cases}|G|,&\ \text{if $x$ is the neutral element, and}\\0,&\ \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Can the continuous Fourier transform also be viewed in this way?

Comment: @littleO See [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, looks interesting!

Answer (score 0):

The discrete Fourier transform is a linear operator $\mathbb{C}^N \to \mathbb{C}^N$ given by $$X(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-2i \pi nk/N}$$ This operator is **orthonormal** which means its inverse is its adjoint :

$$x(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X(k) e^{2i \pi nk/N}$$
we have written the *signal* $x(.)$ as a sum of (complex) sinusoids