# The Role of Group Representation Theory in Signal Processing

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am curious to know what are the clear impact of group representation theory in signal processing.

- For instance, there is *Fourier transform on finite groups*. What are the applications of this form of Fourier transform?
- Are there other specific applications of group representation theory in signal processing?

Please include some details in your answers. Thanks.

Comment: I could try and elaborate on some of the points I brought up in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/324865/11619) or possible [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2233702/11619). I'm not sure where to draw the line. If I go unchecked we will quickly enter $\color{#d00}{\rm TL; DR; alert - red}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I would love to see some elaborations on some of that, especially the Coxeter group stuff (did it scale?).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I am still waiting for your guidance and elaboration.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i'm down for a wall of text.